# Too many redirects error (htaccess)

Tags: error, htaccess, redirects

I recently got an SSL for my website and I'm trying to set up a htaccess so whenever someone joins the site it automatically takes them to the secure version of the site, but whenever I upload my htaccess with the code containing the redirect I got the too many redirect error, this is my code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.scryptedhosting.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This code for some reason results in a too many redirect loop, can anyone help as to why?

Sincerely
Tom.

Comment: Contact your host - some hosts require variations on this rule for it to work. (Arcus Tech are one host I'm familiar with who use a different rule for SSL redirects.)

Comment: Arcustech for example uses

`# Direct to https
 RewriteCond %{ENV:SECURE_REDIRECT} !=on 
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Do you know if there is a load balancer in front of your servers?